# Unable to save to ES from pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm using Jupyter notebook. I have a pyspark dataframe that I loaded using the command below

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /home/hdfs/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.1.2.jar pyspark-shell'

conf = SparkConf(). \
    setAppName('app-name'). \
    setMaster('yarn')

spark = SparkSession.builder. \
    appName("app-name"). \
    config(conf=conf). \
    getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option('delimiter', '|').csv("hdfs://"+ filename )
```

Then I need to save this Dataframe into ElasticSearch by command below:

```
df.write.format("org.elasicsearch.spark.sql") \
    .mode('append') \
    .option("es.resource", flame_index+ "/cdr") \
    .option("es.nodes", "10.10.10.10:9200") \
    .option("es.net.ssl", "true") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "false") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "xxxxx") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "xxxxxx" ) \
    .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location", "file:///tmp/xxxxx.jks") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", "xxxxxx") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.location", "file:///tmp/xxxxx.jks") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.pass", "xxxxxx") \
    .option("es.net.ssl.protocol","TLS") \
    .save()
```

But the command below giving me error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7eb0cfd1dd12> in <module>
     11     .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.location", "file:///tmp/xxxxx.jks") \
     12     .option("es.net.ssl.keystore.pass", "xxxxx") \
---> 13     .option("es.net.ssl.protocol","TLS") \
     14     .save()
     15 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    732             self.format(format)
    733         if path is None:
--> 734             self._jwrite.save()
    735         else:
    736             self._jwrite.save(path)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o145.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasicsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasicsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource
```

The code is running on a hadoop cluster. An ElasticSearch is also in cluster.

I have checked that file /home/hdfs/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.1.2.jar exist

Anybody can help why I'm getting the error above and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try using the elasticsearch-hadoop jar instead of elasticsearch-spark jar.

Comment: I tried to change that, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you able to issue a spark-submit command with command line arguments?

Comment: With spark-submit, I got the same error:
```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o145.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasicsearch.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:244)
```

Comment: Can you paste the command here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was a typo on the line below

```
df.write.format("org.elasicsearch.spark.sql") \
```

It should be **org.elasticsearch.spark.sql**.  I missed one 't' character on it.

Thank you very much guys for trying to help